# How to include Ghostscript with cx_freeze

Tags: python, virtualenv, cx-freeze, python-camelot

Is there a way to include `Ghostscript` with `cx_freeze` in `virtualenv`

I have tried this `pip install python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl` but still getting below error

Downloaded the .whl file from this link - https://pypi.python.org/packages/6a/2d/e2d7474bea24d223d5dc86d51241fd305b75a9168f2e1d7ee07b883c80a5/python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl#md5=0e3a24a374c0d9cc1f2008801ead6927

Error: `RuntimeError: Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed`

Installing the Ghostscript in my Windows system won't solve the problem as I need to include it in my **build** from `cx_freeze` so that non-python installed systems can use my desktop application which is build using `Tkinter`

Basically I am using `camelot` to convert **pdf tables to excel** but it needs `Ghostscript`

Any alternative solutions are more than welcome!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why not simply add the Ghostscript installer to the installer for your desktop application ? This isn't really a Ghostscript question....

Comment: Thanks KenS for your suggestion, but I don't want user to install anything, the application is build to just click a button and convert pdf tables to excel (Multiple files). Installing anything in my organization is not permitted, it needs admin access

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have found an answer

I just need to use `flavor='stream'` in my code as stream doesn't use Ghostscript

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename, pages=input_page_nos, flavor='stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in luck, you may be able to simply zip up your Ghostscript installation, bundle the zip with your software (I'm sure there's a way to bundle up arbitrary files with `cx_freeze`).

You can then have your program unzip Ghostscript to a temporary folder (or a known folder). After that, you'll probably need to hack [`camelot.ext.ghostscript._gsprint.__win32_finddll()`](https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/blob/9137df2f6c6acb2fdaef9256ac42bf11f6afd99e/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py#L187) to only look for the DLL in that installation folder, since there won't be any of those registry keys that would usually exist.

Good luck!